# matplotlib is not a package after install in VSC

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

I've been scouring the other entries for this problem here but most of them are Linux focused.

I'm in my bash shell in VSC and I want to fire up some basic matplotlib code in python.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

coord = [[1,1], [2,1], [2,2], [1,2], [0.5,1.5]]
coord.append(coord[0]) #repeat the first point to create a 'closed loop'

xs, ys = zip(*coord) #create lists of x and y values

plt.figure()
plt.plot(xs,ys) 
plt.show() # if you need...
```

I got into a virtual environment at CLI like so:

```
py -m pipenv --three
```

Then I installed matplotlib successfully.

matplotlib is showing in my pip list as version 3.3.4 and my Python version is 3.8.3. Incidentally, I have installed shapely in the same folder and virtual environment and it works fine for a bare bones snippet of code.

But over and over when I try to run the code above I get:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.pyplot'; 'matplotlib' is not a package

What can I try to fix this?

Comment: which python environment is VSC using?

Comment: \AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe shows in lower left hand corner of my VSC. Thanks @Paul H

Comment: Is that the environment into which you had installed matplotlib?

Comment: I believe so. But following your reasoning I just uninstalled and reinstalled. Reinstall with py-m pipenv install matplotlib. Install shows successful. Error remains the same. 'matplotlib is not a package'

Comment: @Steve Porter -I noticed that the python3.8 you are using is 32-bit. Is the python of the virtual environment you are using 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: Issue resolved. Had to be in the virtual environment to access installations using pipenv command at installation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check if there is a python file named "matplotlib.py", which will cause confusion when VS Code finds the "matplotlib" module package.
2. It is recommended that you find the module "matplotlib" folder in this python environment, then try to delete this folder, and then reinstall it.

   [image]

   [image]

Run:

[image]